# How can I hide a trace in a legend in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a plotly graph with several traces. Some of them I don't want to appear in the legend. How do I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set `showlegend = F` in your trace:

**CODE**

```
library(plotly)
plt <- plot_ly(as.data.frame(mtcars)) %>% 
  add_markers(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, name = 'Fuel Eff.', type = 'scatter') %>% 
  add_markers(x = ~wt, y = ~hp, name = 'Power to wt. ratio', type = 'scatter', 
              showlegend = F) %>%
  layout(
    showlegend = T, 
    legend = list(orientation = 'h')
  )
```

**Output**

[image]