# Remove legend from plot (R plotly shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I created a plot related to the electric vehicle market in Austria:

https://gibraltar.shinyapps.io/esim-v2/

For this I've used shiny for hosting as a WebApp and plotly for the general plotting.

**My problem is that I can't remove the legend (ePCM) on the right side.**

This is the server side of my code (shiny and plotly syntax).

```r
# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Filter data based on selected car model
  filteredData <- reactive({
    if (input$carModel == "Alle") {
      dataSelection
    } else {
      dataSelection[dataSelection$CompleteModelName == input$carModel, ]
    }
  })
  
  # Render the plotly plot
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    evPlot <- plot_ly(
      data = filteredData(), x = ~Reichweitenkosten, y = ~RLL,
      text = ~CompleteModelName,
      color = ~ePCM, size = ~ePCM,
      type = "scatter", mode = "markers"
    )
    
    # Update x-axis and y-axis range to keep them fixed
    evPlot <- evPlot %>% layout(
      xaxis = list(range = c(min(dataSelection$Reichweitenkosten), max(dataSelection$Reichweitenkosten)*1.1)),
      yaxis = list(range = c(min(dataSelection$RLL), max(dataSelection$RLL)*1.1))
    )
    
    evPlot
    
  })
}
```

Could you please help my out?

Among many others I tried the solutions from those links.
I just couldn't remove the legend.

- [Listing legend items horizontally and centered below a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668369/listing-legend-items-horizontally-and-centered-below-a-plot)
- https://statisticsglobe.com/customize-legend-plotly-graph-r
- https://plotly.com/r/legend/
- [How can I hide a trace in a legend in R plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61087468/how-can-i-hide-a-trace-in-a-legend-in-r-plotly)
- https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/plotly/html/hide_legend.html
- https://plotly.com/r/discrete-color/
- [Change legend size in plotly chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245004/change-legend-size-in-plotly-chart)
- https://statisticsglobe.com/change-colors-plotly-graph-r

Answer (score 0):

After browsing for hours I've found the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61088212/21629420

Adding `%>% hide_colorbar()` did the trick. ♥